# No such column 'AssetSourceId' on entity 'CustomBrandAsset'

Tags: apex, experience-cloud, navigation-menu

I have an Apex method that gets the navigation menu items for a given navigation menu, using the `ConnectApi.NavigationMenu.getCommunityNavigationMenu()` method.

When setting `includeImageUrl` to `true`, the following error is returned for guest users of an Experience Cloud site:

```
INVALID_FIELD: 
SELECT Id, ParentId, (SELECT AssetSourceId FROM CustomBrandAssets
                             ^
ERROR at Row:1:Column:30
No such column 'AssetSourceId' on entity 'CustomBrandAsset'. If you are attempting to use a custom field, be sure to append the '__c' after the custom field name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To solve this, the guest user profile needs the **read** permission on the **Documents** object.

Comment: thank you for self-curing and posting the answer. The Community appreciates this